# Call PHP variable in HTML

Tags: php, html, nested

I wrote a code involving nested PHP and HTML parts as below. Why variable "v" is not displayed, But the variable "u" is?

```
<?php

$v= rand (1,15);
$u= rand (1,15);

$h = <<<EOD
            <!DOCTYPE html>
            <html>
            <body>
                    <p style="margin-top:80px">This is a random number:</p>
                    <?php echo $v ?>
            </body>
            </html>
EOD;
            echo $h;

?>

<html>

    <body>
        u=<?php echo $u ?>
    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Your issue is [not reproducible](https://3v4l.org/oGQv2).

Comment: @AksenP — Eh? It's entirely reproducible.

Comment: This is not how heredoc works.

Comment: @Quentin, I mean all variables are displayed as they are, with their values.

Comment: @AksenP your fiddle literally outputs `<php echo somevalue ?>` while there shouldn't be the tags nor the echo

Comment: @AksenP — Not by the time the browser has rendered the HTML.

Comment: @Cid, the question IS `"Why variable is not displayed"`. but it is.

Comment: `<html>` should only be in a page once. I would move the document creation outside the PHP generation. Just use PHP where needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP has two modes.

1. Inside `<?php...?>` (and other PHP tags) PHP code is evaluated
2. Outside those tags, code is streamed directly to the output

You have `<?php echo $v ?>` **inside** a PHP section (inside a string created with HEREDOC).

It doesn't trigger PHP evaluation of the content when the string is created because it is just part of the string. It doesn't trigger PHP evaluation when you later `echo` it because you are just echoing a string.

`<?php echo $v ?>` will be in the (invalid) HTML sent to the browser, and the browser will treat it as an unknown tag. The value of `$v` will be one of the attributes. The browser won't render anything for this unknown tab, but you will be able to see it in the Developer Tools Inspector or with View➝Source

---

Rethink your application design. Don't try to store strings containing PHP code. Generate the string with the data you need in it in the first place.

```
$h = <<<EOD
            <!DOCTYPE html>
            <html>
            <body>
                    <p style="margin-top:80px">This is a random number:</p>
                   $v
            </body>
            </html>
EOD;
            echo $h;
```

Comment: Can I use java script instead of what I wrote